How to get metadata for one temporary table only?
I have created temporary table with the same name #tgi in different sessions.
How can I get metadata for my table only?
declare @table nvarchar(1024)='#tgi'
declare @tableSchema nvarchar(1024)='dbo'
declare @tableName nvarchar(1024)='tempdb.'+@tableSchema+'.'+@table
declare @col varchar(512)= 'id'

select t.name as TableName,c.name as ColumnName 
     from tempdb.sys.identity_columns c
     inner join tempdb.sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
     where t.name like @table+'[_]%' and c.name=@col

This script gives me duplicated rows like



TableName
ColumnName




#tgi____________________________________________________________________________________________0000000000E0
id


#tgi____________________________________________________________________________________________0000000000AC
id



Is it possible to query metadata for my table only ?

Try: WHERE t.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tgi') instead of the LIKE stuff

I'd strongly suggest you rethink whatever it is you are doing, because you really shouldn't ever need such code.

If you created the temp table how do you not know the structure of the table?

@SeanLange I suppose the info could be useful if you need exact details of a table that uses server-defaults or DB-defaults for things like COLLATION (i.e. where you don't actually know the details when you create the temp table) - or maybe they're after some technical column metadata that affects how the data is represented in TDS which a consuming application might want to have).

@Dai you could be right. I guess if they used select into they might need to examine the metadata a bit. Seems unlikely but definitely feasible.
